# e1071 svm predicted probabilties are all 0.5

Tags: svm, e1071

My svm classifier model always predict 0.5 as probabilities.

```
svm.model <- svm(repeater ~ idRepeatBuyRatio + idTotalPurchase + c + d, data = trainData, cost = 100, gamma = 1)

svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testData, probability = TRUE)
head(attr(svm.pred, "probabilities"))
    t   f
1 0.5 0.5
2 0.5 0.5
3 0.5 0.5
4 0.5 0.5
5 0.5 0.5
6 0.5 0.5
```

which is strange because the same call without probabilities actually makes different classifications:

```
> svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testData, probability = FALSE)
> head(svm.pred)
1 2 3 4 5 6 
f t f t f f 
Levels: f t
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post an example of your dataset so we can try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `probability` in the `svm` function is `FALSE`. If you set this to `TRUE` then you ought to get the results you want.